# Swift: Parsing JSON Dictionary Values

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurlsession

I'm trying to parse JSON data.  What I can do is to save JSON data as an NSData file.  Then I can read it as NSDictionary and set some values to respective text fields.  What I cannot do is to put those values from JSON directly to respective text fields.  The source of the data is Open Weather Map.  That's not really important for me.  I just need data to practice JSON parsing.  Anyway, the following is what I have.

```
@IBOutlet weak var coordField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var countryField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var ideeField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var nameField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var cntField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var codField1: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    enum JSONError: String, ErrorType {
        case NoData = "ERROR: no data"
        case ConversionFailed = "ERROR: conversion from JSON failed"
    }

    let urlPath = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID=fb1b5dcb756e9a52c49ee6377a02d879"
    guard let endpoint = NSURL(string: urlPath) else { print("Error creating endpoint");return }
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:endpoint)
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data,response,error) -> Void in
        do {
            guard let dat = data else { throw JSONError.NoData }
            guard let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dat,options:[]) as? NSDictionary else { throw JSONError.ConversionFailed }
            //print(json)

            if let items1 = jsonDict["city"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let a = items1["coord"] {
                    if let lat = a["lat"] as? NSNumber {
                        print("\(lat.stringValue)") // It prints "55.75222"
                        self.coordField1.text = "lat: " + lat.stringValue as String + " "
                    }
                    if let lon = a["lon"] as? NSNumber {
                        print("\(lon.stringValue)") // √
                        self.coordField1.text = self.coordField1.text! + "lon: " + lon.stringValue as String
                    }
                }
            }

            let jdata:NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(jsonDict)
            jdata.writeToFile(self.filePath1(), atomically:true) // saving JSON as an NSData file

        } catch let error as JSONError {
            print(error.rawValue)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()
    }       
}
```

Xcode has forced me to put self before each text field.  I can image why.  Anyway, as a result, I have empty text fields.  The application doesn't crash.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that your code is really setting the text? do those if lets succeed and indeed the values are being set to fields?

Comment: Que!?  My question is why aren't the values set to my text fields?

Comment: That I understand. my question is can you print inside those if let  statements, where your text setting code is present, to ensure the control comes there?  Also that typecasting to NSNumber is unnecessary since the labels need text anyway which is String.

Comment: print("\(lat.stringValue)") prints a number.  If I don't set the value as NSNumber, the application will crash for some values.

Comment: Hi ElTomato, are you using storyboards and have you linked the textfields properly? In addition, simply try to set a hard coded string to your textfields after assigning the json parsed value to see whether you have a reference to the text field.

Comment: Those text fields are connected.

Comment: Can you set the textfield texts in the main thread using `dispatch_async()`

Comment: Basically the code is correct, however you can simplify the code by using `[String:AnyObject]` instead of `NSDictionary` and `Double` instead of `NSNumber`. And assign the value to the text field with `self.coordField1.text = "lat: \(lat) "`. As a suggestion to solve the display problem try to set the text field values on the main thread.

Comment: Okay, guys.  I think there's nothing wrong.  If I wait for 10 seconds or so, the values will be set.  I didn't expect that I had to wait that long.

Comment: @J.Wang is right. I can confirm. I just copy and paste the code and dispatch the updation of text field with the main queue and it works. Docs also states that completion block will be executed on the delegate queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@J.Wang has pointed out the right thing. The problem is UI is not updating on the main thread. As docs states the the `completionHandler` will be executed on the delegate queue so we have to dispatch it with the main queue. By the way i also got warning that this application is trying to modify autolayout on the background thread...

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
   self.coordField1.text = "lat: " + lat.stringValue as String + " "
})
```