# How to Create JSON Object in Swift 2.0?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I want to create an JSON Object Which Contains these things

```
    {
      "user":{
      "email":"foo@example.com",
      "password":"qwertyhello"
             }
     }
```

in swift 2.0

i have to use this Object as Parameters in below function for Server request and i don't have any idea how to create it.
So Any Help?????

```
           request.HTTPBody = try    NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: .PrettyPrinted)
```

Comment: Help yourself by running a search, silly.

Comment: google it a lot But found nothing :(

Comment: See this topics.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394305/swift-parsing-json-dictionary-values  There are more.

Comment: I've linked your question to a duplicate that I know works well (because, well, this is my answer, ahah). It should do what you expect. If it doesn't, leave a comment here and *explain precisely what doesn't work*. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

something like that should work

```
let person: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "name": "Ferdinand",
    "age": 13
]

request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(person, options: .PrettyPrinted)
```

or a even a better way, use Alamofire: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: i have to create a JSON object and send it to the server i have tried this but it didn't work

Comment: Then you have "mistried". This is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Create Dictionary first then **serialize** data using `NSJSONSerialization`.